# Sonarqube coverage result modules name usage

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I'm using sonar to do my code coverage and every time I run my coverage I get three modules: Line, Branch and Method, the branch is what I see in the sonar, but what are the other two?

[image: Sonar image]

Answer (score 1):

Those are not modules, those are coverage metrics.  The "coverage" value that you see in SonarQube is a weighted average of "line" and "branch" coverage.  Line coverage simply measures the number of lines that are covered.  Branch coverage refers to the number of "branches", based on logical expressions in "if" and similar operations.

The following page has some details about this: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/metric-definitions/ .